# bash: build.env/: No such file or directory error trying to Build/Run Cuttlefish on PC/ARM64

Tags: android-source, virtualization, repo, android-kernel

I'm trying to Build/Run Cuttlefish on PC/ARM64. This is the tutorial that Im following :

https://sites.google.com/junsun.net/how-to-run-cuttlefish/home

Im stuck here :

```
root@ziomario-Z390-AORUS-PRO:/media/ziomario/Elements/android-cuttlefish# repo init -u platform/manifest - Git at Google -b pie-gsi

Downloading Repo source from git-repo - Git at Google
remote: Counting objects: 8, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (150/150)
remote: Total 150 (delta 70), reused 150 (delta 70)
Receiving objects: 100% (150/150), 139.35 KiB | 1.74 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (70/70), completed with 14 local objects.
Downloading manifest from platform/manifest - Git at Google
remote: Sending approximately 105.06 MiB …
remote: Counting objects: 1145, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (3/3)
remote: Total 87072 (delta 26102), reused 87072 (delta 26102)
Receiving objects: 100% (87072/87072), 105.06 MiB | 7.15 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (26102/26102), done.

repo has been initialized in /media/ziomario/Elements/android-cuttlefish

root@ziomario-Z390-AORUS-PRO:/media/ziomario/Elements/android-cuttlefish# source build.env/
bash: build.env/: No such file or directory
```

someone can give me some suggestions to fix that eror and goes further with the tutorial ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is misprint in instructions on https://sites.google.com/junsun.net/how-to-run-cuttlefish/home.
AOSP building commands should be used:
$ source build/envsetup.sh